# Ubuntu virtual machine on Windows error once installed: drm:vmn_host_log [vmugfx] *ERROR* Failed to send log

Tags: drm

I have recently installed a VM and Ubuntu, once I finished installing Ybuntu I had the following message

> drm:vmn_host_log [vmugfx] *ERROR* Failed to send log

I´m no programmer and my knowledge is honestly very limited on this, does anyone know how can I solve this?

Comment: getting this recently, try booting it in recovery mode, later on it will start working

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings in the VirtualBox.

Then go to Display.

Then change the Graphic controller to VBOX VGA.

Ubuntu will start working.

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It keeps resetting back to VBOXSVGA, it says invalid settings.

Comment: @john If you read the warning at the bottom of the settings dialog, it says "[...] Either disable 3D acceleration or switch to required graphics controller type.  *The latter will be done automatically, if you confirm your changes*" (emphasis mine).  So make sure to uncheck the "Enable 3D Acceleration" box as well before accepting the changes (you still get a warning about the settings, but its a different one and you can ignore that).

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue as well, but I believe that I found a solution! Here are my configurations that fixed this issue.

- I would ramp up your RAM/base memory to at least 2GB if possible.
- Uncheck the floppy disk in the boot order and move it below the optical and hard disk.
- Leave the graphics controller on VMSVGA, this is not an issue.
- Make sure your Controller:IDE is set to your ISO image.
- Have your network attached to your Bridged Adapter.
- Make sure to choose "Install Ubuntu" instead of "Try Ubuntu."

That should be everything, I believe that your system just didn't have enough RAM to allocate the graphics display for the VM. The error might pop up again, but it should load to the Ubuntu home screen. Here is a link to a PDF that proved incredibly useful for this installation process: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~carnahan/cis4930sp17/SettingUp.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This answer is coming very late, but hopefully it will help someone. To solve this issue you need to unmount the optical drive containing the live image. This is also the case if you are trying to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions and have mounted the live CD.